# Is this a binary operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

For the following set, determine if the given operation is a
binary operation or not.

The set of all 2 × 2 matrices with real entries whose 2, 2 entry is
zero:

$$X=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\c & 0\end{bmatrix} | a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

With matrix multiplication.

Normally id say yes right away but the part thats confusing me is that after its multiplied by anther matrix its very likely that the 0 entry will no longer be a 0 entry does that disqualify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> after its multiplied by anther matrix its very likely that the 0 entry will no longer be a 0 entry does that disqualify it?

Yes.  A binary operation on a set $X$ is a function $X \times X \rightarrow X$.  So the output of multiplying *any* two such matrices must also be a matrix with a zero in the $2,2$ slot.  You can investigate this by multiplying together two general matrices in this set:

$$
\left[
 \begin{matrix}
  a & b  \\
  c & 0
 \end{matrix}
\right] \cdot \left[
 \begin{matrix}
  d & e  \\
  f & 0
 \end{matrix}
\right] = \left[
 \begin{matrix}
  ad + bf & ae  \\
  cd & ce
 \end{matrix}
\right]$$

Given that $c$ and $e$ are arbitrary...

Comment: Thought so thank you very much